# I am using itext to generate pdf. Now , I want to make paragrap align same with table, what should Ido?

Tags: java, itext

[image: pdf view]

Just like the image, I want to make 1 and 3 align same with 2. The table is default alignment.
What should I do?

Comment: The Itext version is 5.5.9.

Comment: check this http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way of doing it , add both to the same paragraph

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class ItextMain {
    public static final String DEST = "simple_table4.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        // file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new ItextMain().createPdf(DEST);
    }

    public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document();

        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("1-Not aligned with table"));

        document.add(new Chunk());

        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.setIndentationLeft(20);// (20);

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
        for (int aw = 0; aw < 16; aw++) {
            table.addCell("hi");
        }
        table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        p.add(table);
        //document.add(table);

        p.add("3- Aligned with table");

        document.add(p);
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The iText 5 `PdfPTable` class has a width percentage attribute which holds *the width percentage that the table will occupy in the page.* By default this value is 80 and the resulting table is horizontally centered on the page, i.e. in particular it is indented.

To prevent this, simply set the percentage value to 100:

```
PdfPTable table = ...;
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
```

Alternatively set the horizontal alignment:

```
table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
```